# check multiple schedules for missing dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a range of dates that I want to see if someone is working or not.

I would like to see an entry for each person against each date, with null or zero if they are not working

E.g. if dates are last week, 6/1 to 6/7, then I would like to see

```
6/1 - Name1 - 1
6/2 - Name1 - 1
6/3 - Name1 - 1
6/4 - Name1 - 1
6/5 - Name1 - 1
6/6 - Name1 - 0
6/7 - Name1 - 0
6/1 - Name1 - 1
6/2 - Name1 - 1
6/3 - Name1 - 0
6/4 - Name1 - 0
6/5 - Name1 - 1
6/6 - Name1 - 1
6/7 - Name1 - 1
```

I have tried a left and a right join, and it doesn't seem to be working, as all dates are used, just not by each person.

Code so far:

```
declare @SchedWeek table
    (
    DateCode varchar(50) primary key
    --I wish I knew who decided the date would be varchar(50)
    )

insert into @schedweek
    (DateCode)
values
    ('20150601'),
    ('20150602'),
    ('20150603'),
    ('20150604'),
    ('20150605'),
    ('20150606'),
    ('20150607')

SELECT [@SchedWeek].[DateCode]
    ,a.* 
from @schedweek 
    left outer join (
    select distinct --because of multiple entries describing schedule in excruciating detail
           [schedDate]
          ,[ssn]
          ,[agentName]
          ,[externalID]
          ,muID 
    FROM [AgtScheduleDetail] ) a
    on [@SchedWeek].[DateCode]=[a].[scheddate]
```

Comment: do you have an agent table?

Comment: yes, I do have a list of agents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your list of agents you can cross join the agent table to the `@SchedWeek` table.  Then use that to left join to your `AgtScheduleDetail` table. Similar to

```
WITH cteAgentSchedule AS
(
    SELECT 
        DateCode,
        [agentName],
        [agentId]
    FROM
        @schedweek, [Agents] -- combine tables
)
SELECT
    a.DateCode,
    a.[agentName],
    (CASE WHEN asd.[agentId] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) [worked]
FROM
    cteAgentSchedule a
    left outer join (
        select distinct --because of multiple entries describing schedule in excruciating detail
               [agentId] -- added for join 
              ,[schedDate]
              ,[ssn]
              ,[agentName]
              ,[externalID]
              ,muID 
        FROM [AgtScheduleDetail] 
    ) asd on a.[agentId] = asd.[agentId] AND a.[DateCode] = asd.[scheddate]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a DimDate table? Brent Ozar has a great video and more information on the applications of DimDate. I had to do this to determine utility over a period of hours/days and with a simple cross join to DimDate, you could complete your query. Here's how I'd write it with the DimDate table:

```
    SELECT employee_ID, dimdate.DATE_ID, 
CASE WHEN scheduleddate = dimdate.date_ID then 1 ELSE 0 END as [EmployeeActiveOnDay]
    FROM EmployeeSchedule
    CROSS JOIN dimdate
```